# Is there a MARS working on GNU/Linux?

Tags: linux, corewar

I am looking for a MARS (a software to run CoreWar warriors) working on GNU/Linux, but the only one I could find (nMars) crashes when I open or create a warrior file.

Comment: The last public release of nMars, which happened in 2007, stopped working in Mono, which is what I assume is used to run a .NET program under Linux. You could try an older version, but WINE sounds like your best bet.

Comment: Welcome at gaming.SE, Valentin! Please don't consider my edit rude, but since ones name is already mentioned at the bottom of a post, salutions are [discouraged per the FAQ](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) for the sake of overview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. There is a variaton of pMars available for Linux. If you use Arch Linux, it is available [in the AUR](http://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=27763). For other distros, you could attempt to download the tarball and compile and install it manually.

Answer (score 3):

For Ubuntu: [pMARS](http://www.koth.org/pmars/) is available from the official Ubuntu repositories from Ubuntu 19.10 (Eaon Ermine) onwards. Install by running `sudo apt-get install pmars`.

For Debian: pMARS is currently in the "testing" distribution of Debian, so it might become available in stable Debian distributions starting from Debian 11 (Bullseye).

Alternatively, you could compile pMARS from [source](https://sourceforge.net/projects/corewar/).